# How Kubernrtes NetworkPolicies works?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

This question might have a very simple answer, but I am trying to understand the following statement regarding the `Kubernetes`'s `NetworkPolicies` found in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#the-two-sorts-of-pod-isolation)

> For a connection from a source pod to a destination pod to be allowed, both the egress policy on the source pod and the ingress policy on the destination pod need to allow the connection. If either side does not allow the connection, it will not happen.

We already know that when a pod starts both `ingress` and `egress` rules are `AllowAll` by default.

According to the above statement, why it doesn't work when in one of the sides, we haven't configured the rules?

For example, if `Pod A` wants to talk to `Pod B`, and if `Pod B` only wants to be talked by the `Pod A`, we could have an `ingress` rule defined for `Pod B`. Accoring to the above statement, why do we need to have an `egress` rule as by default it is `AllowAll`.

Could someone help me on this? Am I misunderstanding the statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some misunderstanding.

For example, if A >>> B only, which means only A will establish a connection to B (A is the client and B is the server)

A only need to enable an egress rule with destination B and block all ingress.

B only needs to enable an ingress rule with source A and block all egress.